# Can you call a stored procedure within a select statement in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In MariaDB I would like to call a stored procedure from within a SELECT statement like this:

```
    SELECT 
      CALL GetInfoForOneRow(hdp.p00) 
    FROM historydataprofile hdp 
    WHERE hdp.id IN ( 1, 22, 333)
```

I want to call the stored procedure once for each of the values 1, 22 and 333. The procedure returns more than one column but only one row.

Is this possible at all? Would it be possible with a function instead? I have tried with a function but without luck as a function cannot return multiple values. Would it be possible with a cursor?

**Edit**
So my problem in the bigger context is that I have to do a reverse pivot, that is creating a result set in the format of "key value pairs" (lots of rows) from data stored as one one row (with lots of columns), on data where each resulting row requires a lot of code.

So what I would like the calling code to look like is this:

```
SELECT GetInfoForOneRow(hdp.p00) FROM scc_historydataprofile hdp WHERE hdp.id = 1 
  UNION ALL
SELECT GetInfoForOneRow(hdp.p01) FROM scc_historydataprofile hdp WHERE hdp.id = 1 
  UNION ALL
SELECT GetInfoForOneRow(hdp.p02) FROM scc_historydataprofile hdp WHERE hdp.id = 1 
  UNION ALL
SELECT GetInfoForOneRow(hdp.p03) FROM scc_historydataprofile hdp WHERE hdp.id = 
...
  UNION ALL
SELECT GetInfoForOneRow(hdp.p99) FROM scc_historydataprofile hdp WHERE hdp.id = 1
```

However I now realize that it is not possible to have neither a function nor a procedure return multiple *columns* which is needed to make the above code work. I will have to look at my query structure again to figure out how to work around this.

**I will be posting a new question if needed**.

Comment: How does the procedure `GetInfoForOneRow` looks like ? Edit the question to add its code as well. Maybe you can do this just in a simple query, instead of using a procedure inside `select`

Comment: Why you dont make a cursor in your stored procedure where you loop through the result io that select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you call a stored procedure within a select statement in MariaDB?

No, not as you want to.

Use a stored function.

Or write the stored procedure so it returns the whole resultset you want (the result of the SELECT statement in your example).

Comment: So the short answer is "no". Which will stop me searching for the non-existing article to show _how_ it's done. Thank you.